How to demolish and remove a small concrete pad?
I have a ~5x5ft concrete pad under my deck. There was a hot tub before we moved in but the hot tub was removed and the deck built over it.
The concrete pad goes all the way to the exterior wall/foundation is not properly graded: When it rains the water will sit on the pad and potentially running towards the foundation as opposed to away.
For that reason I’d like to remove this pad.
What is the easiest way to do this. Is there any way to do this without heavy machinery or a jackhammer?

How much clearance between the deck and the concrete pad?

Neatest way might be with a cement saw that you rent.  Cut in even size squares it can be reused.  Messy is a 10 pound sledge hammer

@JACK Basically none. Would need to remove the planks on the deck …

Sounds like you're gonna have to remove decking no matter what demolition method you pick.

Unless you want to be swinging a sledge hammer for a week, think about renting a small electric jackhammer. I know you mentioned "no jackhammer" but I'm guessing you were referring to the larger ones that need an air compressor. You can rent small, electric ones that weigh 25 to 45 pounds and plug into your regular outlets. I've used them to chop up concrete flooring to replace toilets flanges and drain pipes and they work amazingly well. Chop up small enough pieces so you can haul them away by yourself. Many home stores have tools to rent.

Wear ear and eye protection!

With regards to cost, such tools are sometimes available to buy secondhand where you can sell it again when you are finished with it for almost the same price, so the usage cost becomes very small and cheaper than renting. Also notice that this might produce a non-insignificant amount of dust (although concrete is not as bad as rock), which you can mitigate by having a little water running from a hose.

@Matthew also ear protection and a dust mask.

@divB I suggest that you apologise to the neighbours in advance. Maybe they can schedule to be out when you're doing the work.

Other options - add a skim more concrete and re-grading the slope so it drains properly.
It doesn't have to be thick, but the concrete means there's no way for mud to form under the deck, or for weeds to grow.
Overall cost is probably about the same between disposal of old pad and a couple bags of concrete.
Either way you'll have to lift most/all of the decking to access the area.
Negative: adding more concrete adds more weight, not ideal on a hillside or if you have subsidence problems
Positive: Since the deck was built over the pad, it may have support members that rest on the concrete - so removing the concrete may mean adding some piles or footers for the deck, or trying to demolish all but some small pillars of concrete (which sounds difficult!)
And you'll need to backfill the area where the concrete was anyway, else its going to pond rainwater there.

Or leave it all as-is and simply add a roof over this deck.  This minimises rain water, but may not be suitable for your particular situation.
